# How do I remove Tag in GitLab repository

Tags: git, tags, gitlab

I am using GitLab 7.7.2 and tried to remove Tag in a repository in GitLab.
I could remove tag in a local repository but cannot remove tag in origin.
How do I remove tag in GitLab repository?

```
$ git tag -d Tag_AAA
Deleted tag 'Tag_AAA' (was d10bff2)

$ git push --delete origin Tag_AAA
remote: GitLab: You don't have permission
To git@git.aaa.bbb.ccc:root/Repository.git
 ! [remote rejected] Tag_AAA (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.aaa.bbb.ccc:root/Repository.git'
```

Comment: Here, master branch is not protected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now (GitLab 12.1, July 2019), a developer can remove a (non-protected) tag (not just a maintainer or owner)

See "[Developer role can rewrite/remove Git tags](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/07/22/gitlab-12-1-released/#developer-role-can-rewriteremove-git-tags)"

> Git tags are useful for referencing specific points and are typically used for tagging specific versioned releases.
>
> To make git tags easier to use by development teams, we’re adding the ability to allow Developers to rewrite and remove non-protected tags.
> Protected tags still require Maintainer or Owner permissions.

The [permission matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) has been updated.
See [issue 52954](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/52954).

Answer (score 35):

```
# delete locally:
git tag -d <tag>

# delete remotely:
git push origin :refs/tags/<tag>

# another way to delete remotely:
git push --delete origin <tag>
```

Comment: uncheck repository settings, "Do not allow users to remove Git tags with git push
Users can still delete tags through the GitLab UI."

Answer (score 28):

Obviously you don't have the permission of deleting tags in remote GitLab repo.

Either ask for the owner of the repo to grant you the permission of master or let him help you to delete the tag would help.

Comment: I found that I have developer permission and I need master permission in GitLab to delete tag. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/permissions/permissions.md

Comment: Yeah. You need the permission of master.

Comment: uncheck repository settings "Do not allow users to remove Git tags with git push
Users can still delete tags through the GitLab UI."

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the maintainer or owner role to be able to rewrite/remove Git tags.

See GitLab permissions: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/user/permissions.md

Answer (score 0):

Incase someone use Gitlab UI (version 16.9.0, Jan 2024), you can manually delete protected tags easily. But you **must** have at least the Maintainer role in your project.

To get the tags, go to Project>>Code>>Tags as shows in below. You can delete tags using the delete button.

[image: Setup git tags in Gitlab UI]