# How to fix "You are not allowed to change existing tags on this project." when deleting a remote tag on Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-tag

I want to adjust a server tag, for example to move the tag from first commit to second commit.

I updated the local tag successfully, but when I update the remote tag with

```
$ git push origin --delete tag "SIT/0.0.1"
```

I get:

```
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to change existing tags on this project.  
To http://113.28.25.210/p2p_mo_bank_ios/tfb-9002-i.git
 ! [remote rejected] SIT/0.0.1 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://113.28.25.210/p2p_mo_bank_ios/tfb-9002-i.git'`
```

Comment: You just do not have enought right on the remote repository to remove a tag. It's not a bug, but a configuration / rights issue

Comment: The command itself is okay except that `tag` is not necessary. But the remote server prevents it because of policy or because you have no permission. So you need to contact with the repository owner.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30859615/1615903

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove Tag in GitLab repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858781/how-do-i-remove-tag-in-gitlab-repository)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have permissions to delete tags in remote. Platforms like gitlab usually bring it disabled.

To delete tags in remote is easier:

```
git push origin :<your tag>
```